# Can I break display devices with the xrandr command?

Tags: xorg, xrandr

If use the `xrandr` command and set a wrong resolution/freq/..., can a break my display devices?

For instance, by setting a very high refresh freq that one of the video devices involved (video card, monitor, ...) does not support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the early 90's there was indeed the danger of breaking CRT displays when setting too high frequency, but I don't think this is still a big problem. Modern CRTs should just refuse to work with unsupported frequencies. Still with any CRT there is some danger, at least this is what [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate) says...

Wrong resolution doesn't do any harm.

Comment: +1, not yet accepted... let me play with the display config until I get the one I want, if I break the display in the process I won't accept you answer :)

Comment: +1 @Toto, dude... you made my day! And +1 @fschmitt, because of Toto's comment

Comment: OK @fschmitt... accepted. I couldn't set up the resolution I wanted, but I didn't break anything in the process either. Thanks!